# line-height assigned as pixel value fails

Tags: jquery, css, height, line, pixel

```
$(element).css(options.css).attr(options.attr).addClass(options.class)
//check if element has changed line-height
if($(element).is('p') && _.isString(options.css['line-height'])){

  console.log('line-height assigned: '+ options.css['line-height'] + ' , and now = ' + $(element).css('line-height'))

}
```

spits out:

```
line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal
line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal 
line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal 
line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal 
line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal 
line-height assigned: 33px , and now = normal
```

Why am I unable to assign line-height in px....

jsfiddle here (which works, unlike my code):

http://jsfiddle.net/wyvernmonarch7/S9Scd/

i dont know what im doing wrong in my code, but there is some problem ... what could be causing this

EDIT: options.css, options.attr, and options.class are all OBJECTS. i get no errors in my code.  removing options.attr, and options.class, has no effect. below is what i get when i onsole log in options.css

```
Object {line-height: "15px", width: 87, height: 15, font: "11px arial", color: "#FFFFFF"…}
color: "#FFFFFF"
display: "none"
font: "11px arial"
font-weight: 400
height: 15
line-height: "15px"
pointer-events: "none"
text-align: "center"
width: 87
__proto__: Object

line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal 
Object {line-height: "15px", width: 87, height: 15, font: "11px arial", color: "#FFFFFF"…}
color: "#FFFFFF"
display: "none"
font: "11px arial"
font-weight: 400
height: 15
line-height: "15px"
pointer-events: "none"
text-align: "center"
width: 87
__proto__: Object
line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal
Object {line-height: "15px", width: 87, height: 15, font: "11px arial", color: "#FFFFFF"…}
color: "#FFFFFF"
display: "none"
font: "11px arial"
font-weight: 400
height: 15
line-height: "15px"
pointer-events: "none"
text-align: "center"
width: 87
__proto__: Object

line-height assigned: 15px , and now = normal
```

//////////////

EDIT: being run after window.load

Comment: What is the value os `options.css` and `options.attr`? Unless they are objects with the appropraite keys, this won't work.

Comment: i tried without options.attr, and options.class, no change. the value of options.css is an object. options.css['line-height'] = 15px, or 33px, according to my console statements.

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery's .css() as a setter, you have to pass it an **Object**, not an **Array**. So your options have to look like this:

```
options = {
  css: {
    'line-height': '15px'
  }
}
```

Reference from jQuery's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Simplified fiddle with your options.css: http://jsfiddle.net/UsEeL/1/

Comment: options.css is an object. not an array. added additional information to my post. options.css['line-height'] is getting the line-height property from options.css (which is an object)

Comment: I've added a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UsEeL/1/) with your css options. Still working.

Comment: im doing something wrong. clearly.  both your fiddle and mine work. but it isnt options being an array. it is a valid object. but in my real code, i'm getting console logs that make no sense.

Comment: Maybe you're running jQuery().css() before the document is ready and therefore miss to assign your options to your element? Try wrapping your code in `jQuery(function($) { // your code });`

Comment: this is run well after window.load